# argparse for unknown number of arguments and unknown names

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'd like to fetch all parameters passed to `sys.argv` that have the format
`someprogram.py --someparameter 23 -p 42 -anotherparam somevalue`.

Result I'm looking for is a  namespace containing all the variables, already parsed.

To my understanding, argparse is expecting the user to define what are the parameters he is expecting.

Any way to do that with argparse ?
Thanks !

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Click http://click.pocoo.org/5/, it's more flexible to build you CLI tools.

Comment: @OleksandrYarushevskyi, how about providing an answer using `Click`?  Or are you just a passing `click` salesman?

Comment: Use `parse_known_args` to handle the known arguments, and parse the `extras` yourself as suggested in the answer.  `argparse` gives you, the programmer, control over the inputs.  It isn't needed with simple free form parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj I provided an answer using `Click`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the parameters will always be given in the format `--name value` or `-name value` you can do it easily

```
class ArgHolder(object):
    pass

name = None
for x in sys.argv[1:]:
    if name:
        setattr(ArgHolder, curname, x)
        name = None

    elif x.startswith('-'):
        name = x.lstrip('-')
```

Now you will have collected all arguments in the class `ArgHolder` which is a namespace. You may also collect the values in an instance of `ArgHolder`

Comment: Thanks much, very helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

Using [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) we can build such a command:

```
import click

@click.command(help="Your description here")
@click.option("--someparameter", type=int, help="Description of someparameter")
@click.option("--p", type=int, help="Description of p")
@click.option("--anotherparam", type=str, help="Description of anotherparam")
def command(someparameter, p, anotherparam):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    command()
```

And you will have a help option automatically:

```
$ python command.py --help
Usage: command.py [OPTIONS]

  Your description here.

Options:
  --someparameter INTEGER  Description of someparameter.
  ...
  --help           Show this message and exit.
```

If you need to get all unknown arguments, you can get them from a context in such way:

```
@click.command(context_settings=dict(
     ignore_unknown_options=True,
     allow_extra_args=True,
 ), add_help_option=False)
@click.pass_context
def command(ctx):
    click.echo(ctx.args)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does not it assume that the parameter name must be known in advance (such as in 'someparameter').
i.e: My parameter names are unknown, so I need to support whatever name can come...

Comment: Other than using a decorator syntax I don't see what this adds to ordinary `argparse`.

Comment: @cyberjoac please, I updated answer, hope it will be helpful for you.